# Determine the factor from given product.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose we are to determine the non-zero integers $a, b, c, l, m , n, p, q, r$ such that $abc=90, lmn=54, pqr=12$ and the numbers $6a, 9b, 2c; 10l, 2m, 9n; 15p, 6q, 9r$ are identical in some order.

I was trying to solve this using trial and error way, but that is not a satisfactory approach. I tried to use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic but that too became tedious. I am searching for some method through which problems like this can be solved. Is there any? If yes, please share the source with me. Else show me the path to solve this sum.

I would like to mention that, the solution to the above problem is $12, 30, 27$. But I am getting no idea how did this arrive.

Comment: is there a typo? should it be 6a?

Comment: I am sorry. Yes it was indeed a typo. Thank you for alert

Comment: What number are identical?  Do you mean $6a=9b=2c; 10l= 2m=9n; 15p=6q=9r$ or do you mean $\{6a, 9b, 2c\}=\{ 10l, 2m, 9n\}= \{15p, 6q, 9r\}$

Comment: I mean the second expressions like set wise identical viz $\{6a, 9b, 2c\}=\{10l, 2m, 9n\}=\{15p, 9q, 9r\}$

Comment: So the question should read: "the sets $\{6a, 9b, 2c\},\{10l, 2m, 9n\},\{15p, 6q, 9r\}$ are identical", since order is unimportant in set comparison.

Comment: Yes, I agree... So is there any specific method to solve this question? I think @kyary might have provided a solution but then from today onwards, I am missing it.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/sCaYTW3 here it is, someone deleted my answer for improper formatting unfortunately